# Youtube uploading via Selenium doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I was building a bot to upload videos to youtube via selenium python and it was working fine but now every time the bot reaches the step of uploading the video it gives this :
[oops something went worng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdzkb.png)

the problem is that it was working fine and I don't know what happened, the methods I was using for uploading are `send_keys` and clicking on the upload button and entering the path in the windows upload window via pyautogui

I tried creating another account and it didn't work, I tried `chromedriver`, `undetected_chromedriver` and `edgedriver` and none of them work but when I try to upload them manually it works fine and even when I try to upload them in the selenium browser instance it works fine also

What Is Happening!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am not getting you ? @platipus_on_fire

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to this? https://www.youtube.com/c/RoelVandePaar/featured

Comment: from time to time pages changes structure and code may need also changes. And servers can also make better system to detect bots/scripts - and this may need also changes in code.

Comment: Are you not using [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) because of quota ?